# Identity conflict with inserting data

Tags: sql-server, insert, identity

I got an issue involving running mySQL code in MS SQL server.
I used identities to auto increment id numbers in most tables. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE klant (
    klantnr INTEGER identity (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    bedrijfsnaam VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
)
```

I'm trying to insert this same "klantnr" value that exists in this table in my table Logins, which is defined as a foreign key to the Klant table:

```
CREATE TABLE Logins (
    GebruikersNaam VARCHAR (30),
    Wachtwoord VARCHAR (30),
    Klantnr INT,
    MdwNr INT,
    CONSTRAINT pk_logID PRIMARY KEY (GebruikersNaam),
    CONSTRAINT fk_klantnr FOREIGN KEY (klantnr) REFERENCES klant (klantnr),
    CONSTRAINT fk_mdwnr FOREIGN KEY (mdwnr) REFERENCES medewerker (mdwnr)
)
```

Here are the inserts:

```
INSERT INTO klant VALUES ('Jumbo'); -- (this is the first insert, klantnr is 1)
INSERT INTO Logins VALUES ('KlantTest', 'test', 1, NULL);
```

> Error: Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 302 The INSERT statement
>   conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_klantnr". The conflict
>   occurred in database "DorblogisticsB31B", table "dbo.klant", column
>   'klantnr'.

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM klant WHERE klantnr = 1` is probably empty

Comment: @wero, nope. the fist insert is klantnr = 1.

Comment: did you look into the table?

Comment: @wero, yep. Klantnr = 1 Bedrijfsnaam = 'Jumbo'.

Comment: Drop your tables, re-run the create table scripts without the 3rd constraint. Then run your inserts in order and the statement will run. You are getting that error because it cant find a matching "klantnr" in the parent table.

Comment: Also, medewerker basically works the same as klant, has the same definition as klantnr, but as mdwnr. Plus, in the login table it should be either a klantnr or mdwnr per 'gebruikersnaam', so I can't define them as not null.

Comment: @EaziLuizi, already tried that. I get the same error for mdwnr referring to the Medewerker table as for klantnr referring to the Klant table.

Comment: Is the [tag:mysql] tag relevant? This looks to be a purely [tag:sql-server] question.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you are overlooking something very small, as we usually do with these kinds of errors, run the following sql and see if you get the same results: **(NOTE: not trying to use best practices or anything, just trying to get you to your answer)**

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Logins', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
      DROP TABLE dbo.Logins; 

    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.klant', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
      DROP TABLE dbo.klant; 

    CREATE TABLE klant (
        klantnr INTEGER identity (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
        bedrijfsnaam VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
    )

    CREATE TABLE Logins (
        GebruikersNaam VARCHAR (30),
        Wachtwoord VARCHAR (30),
        Klantnr INT,
        MdwNr INT,
        CONSTRAINT pk_logID PRIMARY KEY (GebruikersNaam),
        CONSTRAINT fk_klantnr FOREIGN KEY (klantnr) REFERENCES klant (klantnr)
    )



    --re run this query 3 times...
    INSERT INTO klant VALUES ('Jumbo');
    INSERT INTO Logins VALUES ('KlantTest' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,(SELECT MAX(klantnr) FROM klant)),
                                 'test', 
                                 (SELECT MAX(klantnr) FROM klant) 
                                 , NULL);


    SELECT * FROM klant
    /*
    OUTPUT:
    1   Jumbo
    2   Jumbo
    3   Jumbo
    */
    SELECT * FROM Logins

    /*
    OUTPUT:
    KlantTest1  test    1   NULL
    KlantTest2  test    2   NULL
    KlantTest3  test    3   NULL
    */
```

Comment: Yeah.. I tried inserting the login data before the klant data. No wonder it does not work... Anyhow, it's fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

WORKAROUND
Here are two ways to work around this:
Define all the columns used in a foreign key constraint as NOT NULL.

-or-

Update all the columns used in a foreign key constraint in the same update statement.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/256307
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62325/how-to-solve-the-error-msg-547-level-16-state-0-line-1

Answer (score 0):

After inserting into [klant] try this:

```
SELECT * FROM klant WHERE bedrijfsnaam='Jumbo'
```

in that way you can find out what ID number is assigned to 'Jumbo'. And then with this ID you can insert values into [logins].

Comment: When I execute that query, I get: Klantnr = 1, Bedrijfsnaam = 'Jumbo'.
Then when I do the insert: INSERT INTO Logins VALUES ('KlantTest', 'test', 1, NULL); It does not work, and I get the error.

Comment: And the error message is same what you have posted above? Are you writing query within TRANSACTION or not? or if autocommit is disabled on your server there is chance your INSERT is not committed. Please check abovementioned SELECT in another session.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It was the most stupid mistake ever. I tried inserting the Login data before inserting the klant data...